# bash delete older files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, recursive-backtracking

I have this unique requirement of finding 2 years older files and delete them. But not only files as well as corresponding empty directories. I have written most of the logic but only thing that is still pending is , when I delete particular file from a directory , How can I delete the corresponding directory when it is empty. As when I delete the particular file , the ctime/mtime would also accordingly get updated. How do I target those corresponding older directories and delete them?
Any pointers will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

- Admin

Comment: Could you show us the code you have so far? `rm -r mydir` to remove directory and contents

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +730 -delete
```

`-mtime +730` finds files which are older than 730 days.

Please be careful with this kind of command though, be sure to write `find /path/to/files* -mtime +730` beforehand and check that these are the files you want to delete!

**Edit:**
Now you have deleted the files from the directories, `-mtime +730` won't work.
To delete all empty directories that you have recently altered:

```
find . -type d -mmin -60 -empty -delete
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes that makes sense and like mentioned before , I have got so far. The part which is still pending is , how do I target(delete) the directories which will be empty after I delete the older files within.

Comment: Sure, so you want to delete the now empty directories, check my edit @SachinH

Comment: Sorry but you missed the point again. Once you delete the older files the corresponding empty directory will no longer be *old* i.e will mtime and ctime be modified.

Comment: @SachinH So then just delete all the old directories initially? `find . -type d -mtime +730 -exec rm -rv {} \;`

Comment: If you mean you want to delete all the files older than 2 years and then check if that directory is empty you should probably write a script to do so, else just do one then the other @SachinH

Comment: That would be very risky as the users constantly update those directories.

Comment: If you ever did find a risk-free method of doing this I'd love to see it, thank you @SachinH